# Use Selenium Driver When Created Outside Object

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-3.7

I'm having an issue where when I pass a Selenium driver object and assign it as an attribute of said class, that nothing happens when I call it from inside that class.  An abstraction of what I'm trying to do is this, though I created this also and verified that this also doesn't work:

```
def get_driver():
     chrome_path = r'C:\path\to\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'
     options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=chrome_path)
     return driver


class Page:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        

    def get_page(self, url):
        print(1)
        self.driver.get(url)
        print(2)
        
driver = get_driver()

p = Page(driver)
p.get_page('http://somepage.com')
```

The output of the above is:

> 1
>
> 2

But selenium does not get the page.  But when I run it outside the class like this:

```
driver = get_driver()
driver.get('http://somepage.com')
```

Selenium does retrieve the page.

Why is the driver inside the class unresponsive when I call it from a class to which I have assigned it?

I'm running this on Win 10 with Python 3.7 and Chrome version 79.x.

Comment: Humm.... your first block of code is working for me and opening the page.

Comment: When was the last time you updated your `chromedriver.exe`?

Comment: Updated yesterday. Very interesting maybe problem with my environment. Ugh,I should do ye old "turn it off and on again". Sorry 30 opened windows...

Comment: Lol I guess the next question is how long has it been since you restarted your machine?  If its still an issue reply on here, I have a few more things to try.

Comment: ... yeah so as it turns out that "htts" isn't a valid protocol.  I typed it in correctly here but made the mistake twice in both the original code I wrote AND the minimally abstracted example. Knew I should have had coffee this morning.  I guess I assumed if you entered an invalid URL it would yell at you or do something not just stay on the about:blank page

Comment: This is interesting though. Entering `htts://somepage.com` manually and hitting enter results in a google search but `driver.get("htts://somepage.com")` sits on the blank page.  Glad to hear you found the root cause though.